# How do I get my computer to always use the same ipaddress?

Tags: networking

How do I get my computer to always use the same ipaddress, currently this seems to be allocated by the router then if that machine is shutdown and another machine started then the ipaddress can be allocated to that machine instead.

I would much prefer it if each computer always used the same ipaddress.

Computers on the network are:

PC
Macbook
ipad
linux machine
nas

and some can be connected wireless, via ethernet or both (whihc seem to both have their own ipaddress)

Help with even configuring some of these oses would be useful

Comment: You want to set a static IP address (locally) OR set a reservation (on the server).  However, without knowing the model of your router, we cannot help any further.

Comment: Sorry its a Thomson TG585 v7 router

Comment: Google seems to suggest you cannot do it on the router (the DHCP server) with this god awful piece of equipment.  Although, if you really want to learn and you are adventurous, you should be able to install [OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/thomson/tg585) on it.  Therefore, your only other option is to assign static addresses to your devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for static IP settings.

[Windows instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/19249/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-address-in-xp-vista-or-windows-7/)

[Linux instructions](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-configure-a-static-ip-address-tutorial/) (May differ depending on distribution in use)

[Mac instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/22161/how-to-set-up-a-static-ip-in-mac-os-x/)

[iPad instructions](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/19/manual-dhcp-static-ip-address-ios/)

Your NAS is probably Linux-based, so try following those instructions when configuring that.

Comment: Another option, to avoid issues if you bring your computer to various networks where you don't know the subnet by default, is to set up your router to dynamically assign static IP's (sounds wrong, I know).  But based on MAC/HOSTNAME, many routers support specified IPs.  (DD-WRT on anything, my ASUS router has `Administration > Specified IP`.  I find the router to be a better way to do it since doing the above could potentially cause you headaches if you forget and are connecting somewhere new.

Comment: The answer is correct as far as it goes, but, before you set a static address, you should reserve a range of addresses on your internal subnet for static use.  That involves logging into the configuration panel of your modem/firewall/WiFi device (whichever of them is acting as DHCP server to your internal network) and tell the device to restrict dynamic allocations to a portion of the address space that it controls.  Then, you can administer the remaining addresses statically.

Comment: @Ron  Good point.  At home I have two machines running static at 100 and 101, but dynamic everything else between 2 and 99 (reserving 1 for the router).

Comment: @Kruug thanks, taking the Mac as an example would it be better to use the 'Use DHCP with Manul Address' option, looks simpler rather than the fully manual option.

Comment: What if I want it to work also in a WIFI of a coffee shop? not only in my house?